# Impossible do import users to firebase, hashing issues

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, sha1, pbkdf2

I'm unable to successfully import users to firebase.

I have a list of users for which I only know the salt and hashed password. I know that the function used to create the hash was the following ([crypto lib for nodejs](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html)) :

```
crypto.pbkdf2(password, salt, 20, 44, "sha1", callback)
```

I found that [this website](https://asecuritysite.com/encryption/PBKDF2z) was giving me the exact same hash when giving the same configurations (rounds and salt).

I tried importing users into firebase this way, but without any success :

```
admin
  .auth()
  .importUsers(
    [
      {
          uid: "9",
          email: "testuser@test.com",
          //password = testPassword
          passwordHash: Buffer.from("C6B7Uch6Q+NiiUZVqjRqPit9e+56YkA0xwwZtfs0+RI=",'base64'),
          passwordSalt: Buffer.from("testSalt",'base64'),

      }
    ],
    {
      hash: {
          algorithm: "PBKDF_SHA1",
          rounds: 20,
          dk_len: 44
      }
    }
  )
  .then(function(results) {
    results.errors.forEach(function(indexedError) {
      console.log("Error importing user " + indexedError.index);
    });

      firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword("testuser@test.com", "testPassword")

          .then(function(ok){
              console.log("It's working");
      })

          .catch(function(error) {
               var errorCode = error.code;
               var errorMessage = error.message;
               console.log(error);
      });

  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error importing users:", error);
  });
```

Which gives me :

```
{ [Error: The password is invalid or the user does not have a password.]
```

There is something I cannot figure out, I tried many things including changing algorithms in the firebase hash config, changing Base64, using hash_input_order or changing key-len.

Basically I'm a bit lost and would love some help to resolve this, does anyone has a clue?

Thanks in advance.